# System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users/..../chris.JPG' because it is being used by another process.'

Tags: c#

i have a project for shopping. im new to c# and my project is 3 layer. its code first too. i have a form for users where you can add, edit or delete one user.
i have 2 problem when i want to edit users.
1.when i want to change picture of one my users, i use the same code that i used for add user. but it says that picture is null!
2.second problem is he gives me Exception that i mentioned in title!!please help me..

my presentation layer code for create :

```
User u = new User(); 
u.Name = FnameLname.Text; 
u.UserName = username.Text; 
u.Password = pass.Text; 
u.Pic = SavePic(username.Text); 
u.RegDate = DateTime.Now; 
UserGroup ug = new UserGroup(); 
ug = UGBLL.ReadN(accessgroup.Text); 
bll.Create(u, ug);
```

my data access layer code for create :

```
public string Create(User u,UserGroup ug)
{             
    u.UserGroup = db.UserGroups.Find(ug.id);             
    db.Users.Add(u);             
    db.SaveChanges();             
    return "done.";         
}
```

my methods for saving picture :

OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
Image img;

```
public string SavePic(string username)
{
    string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + @"/UsersPic/";
    string PicName = username + ".JPG";
    string PicPath = OFD.FileName;

    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
    try
    {
         File.Copy(PicPath, path + PicName, true);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return path + PicName;
}

private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    OFD.Filter = "JPG(*.JPG)|*.JPG";
    OFD.Title = "choose picture";
    if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        img = Image.FromFile(OFD.FileName);
        userpicture.Image = img;
        userpicture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    }
}
```

my presentation layer code for edit:

```
User u2 = new User();
u2.Name = FnameLname.Text; 
u2.UserName = username.Text; 
u2.Password = pass.Text; 
u2.Pic = SavePic(username.Text); 
bll.Update(u2, id);
```

my data access layer code for edit:

```
public string Update(User m,int id) { 
    User u = db.Users.Find(id); 
    u.Name = m.Name; 
    u.UserName = m.UserName; 
    u.Password = m.Password; 
    u.Pic = m.Pic; //here it shows that m.pic is null.  
    db.SaveChanges(); 
    return "Done."; 
}
```

i tried to use an exclusive number for each picture name but it didnt worked

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: As an aside, putting files in the executable path is generally a bad idea, depending on who installs / uses this. Many users will not have write permissions to the Program Files directory in an enterprise setting. Recommended to use the user temp file location. Also, "but it didnt worked" - what exactly didn't work?

Comment: If you're trying to overwrite a file that your UI has loaded and is using, that may be problematic. Can't tell based on what you posted if that may be the case.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for `Image.FromFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) says that

> The file remains locked until the Image is disposed.

The workaround for this misfeature is to:

1. Use `Image.FromFile` to produce a file-bound image
2. Clone that image (it will be a separate copy in memory, not bound to the file)
3. Dispose of the file-bound image.

Use the clone where you previously had used the image returned by `FromFile`.